# Shorter code for "if" Jquery condtion

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, for-loop

This code snippet is used for displaying 10 questions consequently after each other and manipulate each question visibility through CSS .hideme class. Then to send the metrics data to Google analytics. 
It works but looks too bulky. I'm trying to rewrite this code in shorter (smarter) format. Any suggestions?

```
  <script>
    (function($) {
    $(":input").change(function(){
        $(this).closest("div").addClass("hideMe");
        $(this).closest("div").next("div").removeClass("hideMe");

        if($('#q2').is(':visible')) {
          ga('send', 'event', 'EnglishHearingWidget', 'question', 'Question 1 Answered');
        }

        if($('#q3').is(':visible')) {
          ga('send', 'event', 'EnglishHearingWidget', 'question', 'Question 2 Answered');
        }

        if($('#q4').is(':visible')) {
          ga('send', 'event', 'EnglishHearingWidget', 'question', 'Question 3 Answered');
        }

        if($('#q5').is(':visible')) {
          ga('send', 'event', 'EnglishHearingWidget', 'question', 'Question 4 Answered');
        }

        if($('#q6').is(':visible')) {
          ga('send', 'event', 'EnglishHearingWidget', 'question', 'Question 5 Answered');
        }

        if($('#q7').is(':visible')) {
          ga('send', 'event', 'EnglishHearingWidget', 'question', 'Question 6 Answered');
        }

        if($('#q8').is(':visible')) {
          ga('send', 'event', 'EnglishHearingWidget', 'question', 'Question 7 Answered');
        }

        if($('#q9').is(':visible')) {
          ga('send', 'event', 'EnglishHearingWidget', 'question', 'Question 8 Answered');
        }

        if($('#q10').is(':visible')) {
          ga('send', 'event', 'EnglishHearingWidget', 'question', 'Question 9 Answered');
        }

        if($('#results').is(':visible')) {

          ga('send', 'event', 'EnglishHearingWidget', 'question', 'Question 10 Answered');
          ga('send', 'event', 'EnglishHearingWidget', 'question', 'Results displayed');

          document.getElementById('answer1').innerHTML = $("input[name=qo1]:checked").val();
          document.getElementById('answer2').innerHTML = $("input[name=qo2]:checked").val();
          document.getElementById('answer3').innerHTML = $("input[name=qo3]:checked").val();
          document.getElementById('answer4').innerHTML = $("input[name=qo4]:checked").val();
          document.getElementById('answer5').innerHTML = $("input[name=qo5]:checked").val();
          document.getElementById('answer6').innerHTML = $("input[name=qo6]:checked").val();
          document.getElementById('answer7').innerHTML = $("input[name=qo7]:checked").val();
          document.getElementById('answer8').innerHTML = $("input[name=qo8]:checked").val();
          document.getElementById('answer9').innerHTML = $("input[name=qo9]:checked").val();
          document.getElementById('answer10').innerHTML = $("input[name=qo10]:checked").val();

          document.getElementById('total1').innerHTML = $('input.yes:checked').length;
          document.getElementById('total2').innerHTML = $('input.yes:checked').length;

          if($('input.yes:checked').length > 2)
          {
            $('#first').hide();
            $('#second').show();
          }
          else
          {
            $('#first').show();
            $('#second').hide();**strong text**
          }
        }
    });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you see any patterns there? Can you imagine a way of repeating that pattern in a [`for` loop?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: I bet a structure like `{ q5: "Question 4 Answer", ... }` could store all your data, then you could loop over that.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I see the pattern, but don't know how to actually write it with "for loop".

Comment: The `dry` tag was indeed relevant, btw.

Comment: @Laziz If a `for` loop gives you a variable (typically `i`) that counts up and you're going from `#q2` to `#q10` do you think you could use the `for` loop variable to generate those strings? What about the "Question N Answered" strings? I bet you could use the `for` loop variable for that as well.

Comment: ^ For loop or maybe a switch (of course for loop would condense code more)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give each checkbox a class and loop through

```
$(".checkboxes").each(function(){
id = $(this).data("id");
if($('#q' + id ).is(':visible')) {
          ga('send', 'event', 'EnglishHearingWidget', 'question', 'Question ' + id  + ' Answered');
        }
});
```

**Update**

Add data-id="qN" to each radio button. and use the above modified code. (I changed ATTR to DATA. Since the div will have that ID and not the radio button.

Comment: How do you know that the `#qN` elements are checkboxes?

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it.

Comment: I actually assumed #qN was a div wrapping the checkbox. However @Blazemonger is correct, not enough information was provided so it was mostly assumptions.

Comment: #qN are actually referring to Divs' id wrapping  each form element and question. The form elements are radio buttons with yes/no option.

Comment: I modified my answer to take into consideration an issue that I realized from your comment @laziz.

Comment: @imvain2 Thanks for feedback, will try.

Answer (score 0):

So you can use switch statement in Javascript

```
switch ($foo) {
case 'bar':
    alert('bar');
    break;
case 'bar2'
    alert('bar2');
    break;
default:
     alert('foo');
}
```